# synchronizing video with timer using actionscript 3.0

Tags: video, actionscript

Is it possible to synchronize video with the global timer? For example, i have information about when to start video, when to pause, when to rewind and when to forward etc. 
I need to control video based on this information. Access to video and the informations are via xml file. Is it possible to implement this using Actionscript 3.0?

Note: time reference here  is not the time of video. its the time obtained from information. So i dont think we can do using cue points.

I have explained  the following with the help of code.

My Current fla file to play the video looks like this

```
import fl.video.*;
var video_x:Number;
var video_y:Number;
var myvideos:XMLList;
var mylogfile:XMLList;
var main_container:Sprite;
var my_player:FLVPlayback;
var myxmlfile:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myxmlfile.load(new URLRequest("config.xml"));
myxmlfile.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,processxml);
function processxml(e:Event):void{
var myxml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
video_x=myxml.@video_x;
video_y=myxml.@video_y;
myvideos=myxml.VIDEO; // reads the video tag from xml
mylogfile=myxml.LOG;// reads the log tag from xml
playvideo();// play the video 
 }
 function playvideo():void {
my_player = new FLVPlayback();
my_player.x = video_x;
my_player.y = video_y;
my_player.width = 480;
my_player.height = 270;
my_player.source = myvideos[0].@url;
addChild (my_player);
 }
```

My xml file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<playlist video_x="30" video_y="10">
<VIDEO title="stephen" url="video/stephen.flv"/>
<LOG realtime="100" state="PLAY" videotime="0"/>
<LOG realtime="200" state="PAUSE" videotime="100"/>
<LOG realtime="400" state="PLAY" videotime="100"/>
<LOG realtime="500" state="REWIND" videotime="40"/>
<LOG realtime="900" state="STOP" videotime="440"/>
</playlist>
```

videotime in xml file represents time of video. 
Realtime in xml file represents global time.
Now based on the realtime in xml file, I need to control the video.

Thanks in Advance for the help,

Thothadri

Comment: Yes, this is possible to do. You might want to show/explain what you have done/tried already, so someone can help. If you don't know where to start, I would recommend doing some searches for how to use a NetConnection/NetStream to work with video in Flash.

Comment: Hey Sunil, thanks a lot for response. I have modified the question accordingly. You have any ideas ?  My friend told me Timer can be used to resolve this problem . But I am not sure whether thats the best way to do. But i have started implementing this using timer.

Comment: Yes, a `Timer` seems like the best approach to implement this :)